# cant stop mod_rewrite overwrite url in browser

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have in my htaccess file the following code

`RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,R]`

this works almost fine but appends the querystring in the url after rewriting. i dont want this. if i delete the R-Flag, even if i delete both flags, it wont work.

i want to overwrite

```
/post/123 => index.php?p=123

/page/123 => index.php?page_id=123

/category/123 => index.php?cat=123
```

but show `/post/123` etc in browser url

Comment: So you want redirect from `index.php?p=123` to `/post/123`?

Comment: No, the other way. if a visitor type www.host.com/post/123 my script should display index.php?p=123 but in the browser should be post/123

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense of redirecting `[R]` if you don't want the url to be change.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?page_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ index.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You should append `[L]` flag also which terminate processing further rules.

Comment: i tried [L,QSA] and it dont work.. but exact the same code with [R,QSA] works (with changing url)

Comment: @ManuelZ You should enter `post/123` and it will work try `var_dump($_GET);` in `index.php`. Also show your full htaccess contents

Comment: when i type localhost/post/242 it displays index.php and var_dump shows `array(1) { ["p"]=> string(3) "242" }` but it doesnt display the requested article..

Comment: @ManuelZ So it is working. Why you said it don't work? Explain not working.

Comment: this is the content of my htaccess `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?page_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ index.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]` maybe its importand that i include the specific php part within a php class and include it in index.php

Comment: i am wondering. now all content it also accessible vie localhost/post/?p=123 etc..

Comment: What _all content_? You have to take care the `$_GET['p']` in your application logic, to not allow any other contents.